# Selecting records with multiple between clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having trouble getting a `sql STATEMENT` to work.

I want to select records that are `BETWEEN` date 1 and date 2 and also

records that are `BETWEEN` date 3 and date 4.

This query is yielding no results.

(the values in single quotes are just pseudocode)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Items
WHERE   ( ( PostDate BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2 )
          AND ( PostDate BETWEEN Date3 AND Date4 )
        )
```

Reading back this query it sounds like im asking the db to give me

records that are between date 1 and date 2 but also in between date 3 and date 4,

which does not make any sense.

How would I translate *Give me records that are between date 1 and date 2 and

records that are between date 3 and date 4 in one batch

Comment: Use OR instead of AND like this ((PostDate BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2) OR (PostDate BETWEEN Date3 AND Date4))

Comment: @Jade He has mentioned "How would I translate Give me records that are between date 1 and date 2 and records that are between date 3 and date 4 in one batch"

Comment: see @Akshay answer below He made it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'AND' condition is wrong in this case. Use 'OR' condition instead

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Items WHERE ((PostDate BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2) OR (PostDate BETWEEN Date3 AND Date4))
```

Comment: That is so weird. That looks like it would give me either set of records but not both.

Comment: Ok.I'll explain. You have 2 conditions in query. Suppose if 1st Condition is date between 1-5 and second is 10-15. If 1st condition return date 4 then how could it be between 10-15.

So either will be correct. I think you got it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use union and divide this query into 2 queries.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Items WHERE PostDate BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2 
union
SELECT * FROM dbo.Items WHERE PostDate BETWEEN Date3 AND Date4
```